# Should we redirect Game Identifications to other SE (or even non-SE) sites?

Tags: discussion, game-identification, migration

From time to time we do get a few Game Identification questions, that are off-topic since they lack images. However, is it acceptable if we redirect users towards other domains where they can get their answer? For example:

*What is the videogame that featured X and Y features, based on a real playing-card game?*

That is off-scope for Arqade, however it wouldn't be too far fetched to assume that the folks over at Card Games would be able to identify the game (if it doesn't break their own rules).

Furthermore, there are other websites, such as a particular subreddit which is dedicated solely to identifying games (even without images), so that would help out some users.

Should we just say *"no, this is off-topic. I'm sorry"*, or alternatively *"This is off-topic, try [here]"* ?

Comment: FML, I searched, but couldn't find any discussion on that. After posting, I found it VTC'ing this

Comment: While related, I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question focuses on added recommendations to our close reasons, while your question focuses on leaving recommendations as a comment. While this is addressed in my answer over there, we don't judge duplication on answers.

Comment: That is why I didn't just outright delete the question, but it's (imo) a bit of a cointoss on the dupe-o-meter

Answer (score 5):

We close Game Identification questions without an audiovisual artifact because they're just not a good fit for our Q&A format, but that doesn't mean we don't want to help users track down a game. Due to this there's nothing wrong with redirecting users to chat or another site (like reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick) which would be better suited to helping them. We should just make sure to do so via comments though, [instead of as part of a close description](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12184/8350).

Answer (score 3):

If the game has a scifi/fantasy setting, such identification questions *might well* be on-topic on https://scifi.stackexchange.com under the [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) tag.

Comment: I think we need to make our stance more clear- while these questions don't the q&a format here, they work fine on another page using the same format.

Comment: Same format, different community. What can I say.

Answer (score 1):

Following a [larger discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13489/28182) around how we can better help users that visit our site, Arqade now has two [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions for suggesting good places to go for off-topic Identification and Recommendation questions:

- [My game identification question was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13525/28182)
- [My request for recommendations was closed as off-topic. Where can I ask for help instead?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13548/28182)

Thus, leaving a comment linking to these FAQs on relevant off-topic questions would be a good place to start.

Please also feel free to add fresh answers to these FAQ posts if you know of any other/new places that accept these types of questions.